# javascript line preventing google app from running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I had a google app running perfectly until I added this script:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(email){
    alert(email);
}
```

It wont even launched now. Did I write it correctly?

Comment: This is probably not the answer, but have you tried changing it to

Comment: `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo = function(email){
 alert(email);
}`

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could select my answer as the one that worked as I'm a very new user and am trying to get reputation. It should also give you some, too, I think.

Comment: Glad to help! Hope your project goes well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your syntax error, you also can't use alert() within a chrome app.

From [here](http://www.developer.com/lang/your-first-chrome-packaged-app.html).

> It is also worth noting that the "alert()" function isn't supported in
>   Chrome packaged apps. If you need to pop a message that blocks the UI,
>   I would highly recommend the jQuery based blockUI plugin.

alert() blocks the javascript execution and messes with the flow, so google disabled it for chrome apps.

Comment: [Full list of other features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) that have also been disabled

Comment: Why a library instead of the native dialog element?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer, but have you tried changing it to

`chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo = function(email){ alert(email); }`